# How to remove space after a section, and remove before a subsection?

Tags: titlesec

I'm trying to get rid of the blank lines that appear after I begin a section, and between subsections (so before a subsection?)

Currently I'm using

```
    \usepackage{titlesec}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-6em}
\titleformat{\section}
       {\normalfont\bfseries}% formatting commands to apply to the whole heading
       {\thesection}% the label and number
       {0.0em}% space between label/number and subsection title
       {.{} }% formatting commands applied just to subsection title
       []% punctuation or other commands following subsection title
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]% runin puts it in the same paragraph
       {\normalfont\bfseries}% formatting commands to apply to the whole heading
       {\thesubsection}% the label and number
       {0.0em}% space between label/number and subsection title
       {}% formatting commands applied just to subsection title
       []% punctuation or other commands following subsection title
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]% runin puts it in the same paragraph
       {\normalfont\bfseries}% formatting commands to apply to the whole heading
       {\thesubsection}% the label and number
       {0.0em}% space between label/number and subsection title
       {}% formatting commands applied just to subsection title
       []% punctuation or other commands following subsection title
 \setlength{\parskip}{0cm}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

I would provide a MWE, but I'm using the NiH grant proposal template, with a bunch of other structural files.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at `\titlespacing`?